# How to apply 3 tier architecture for my VSTO addin?

Tags: c#, excel, architecture, vsto, 3-tier

So I'm happy to use 3 tier Architecture to my APIs n such but I have a problem implementing it to my VSTO AddIn (but maybe I shouldn't?). Anyways here's my non-working solution;

My VSTO have a button to recieve all Objects.

```
private void Bt1_Click(object sender, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        ObjectManager objManager = new ObjectManager(new ExcelObjectDal());
        var allObjects = objManager.GetObjects();
        //Add all objects to WinForm
    }
```

and my ObjectManager, located in my Business Layer:

```
public class ObjectManager : IObjectService
{
    public IObjectDal ObjectDal { get; set; }
    public ObjectManager(IObjectDal DAL)
    {
        ObjectDal = DAL;
    }

    public List<Object> GetObjects()
    {
        Worksheet sheet = ObjectDal.GetObjects();
        //Business logic to extract each object from the sheet
        return new List<object>();
    }
}
```

and here's my DAL:

```
public class ExcelObjectDal : IObjectDal
{
    private Workbook book;
    public ExcelObjectDal()
    {
        this.book = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook);
    }
    public Worksheet GetObjects()
    {
        Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(book.Worksheets[name]);
        return sheet;
    }
}
```

My problem is that my workbook isn't available from anywhere but my VSTO. So should I just create it in one big project and forget about layering or how do I access my data (Excel sheets) from anywhere but VSTO?

Comment: Commenting to the stated qusetion: "How do I access my data (Excel sheets) from anywhere but VSTO?" I'm not sure how you mean that question. Nor is it clear whether this is a VSTO add-in or a document-level customization. But in any case, if all you want is the *data*, with no user interaction, use an OLEDB connection to the *closed* workbook. Of, if the workbook is open, use the "interop", by-passing the VSTO part.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that VSTO is effectively a plugin framework.  Using a 3-tier architecture inside of a plugin framework is going to feel awkward at best, doing so will require discarding large amounts of the framework and rolling your own.

So, for example, your DAL should not be returning Worksheets, instead you should roll your own DTO that extracts the bits you need and pass it up the chain.  I would pass the object needed to invoke the DAL from the UI layer (ideally it's in an IoC container, but this works as well).

This will require writing quite a bit of code, but your business and UI layer will largely be decoupled from the lower levels.  Personally, I'd either see if you could either utilize or roll your own IoC that can be called from the VSTO layer.  Something that can pass the workbook into the constructor for the DAL.

This is a LOT of plumbing to isolate your manager from excel, it may or may not be worth it.  It depends on the ultimate complexity of your business logic, and how testable you need it to be.  Plugins generally don't need to be isolated from the objects they are plugged into...

Comment: Very thanks for your response. I would like to keep it 3 layered since I already started and I have a deadline coming up pretty soon. Would it be okay to return an Excel Range from my DAL with only the chosen objects cells? Then my DAL looksl method is: Xcl.Range GetObjectByName(string name); and my BLL method to my UI is: Object GetObjectByName(string name); so what I'm doing is that my BLL recieves an Excel Range, does some magic and returns an instance of my Object class populated from the Excel Range.

Comment: As I understand you, I should retrieve my Object from the Excel Sheet in the DAL and return the Object instead?

Comment: No, you shouldn't return the object at all, you should return what the UI layer "needs" from the object.  That's how you decouple.

Comment: Although once again, I question the value of decoupling from excel in what is effectively an excel plugin.